# What's the ggvis equivalent of stat_function in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm looking to plot a function using ggvis - is there something similar to stat_function in ggplot2?

For example:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,1)), aes(x=x)) + 
    stat_function(fun=dbeta, args=list(shape1=2, shape2=10))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not yet found an equivalent `ggvis` version of `ggplot2::stat_function()`.  However, I have used the following work-around using `ggvis::add_data()` and `ggvis::layer_paths()`.

For example: The following will add a parabolic curve to a `ggivs` scatter plot:

```
mtcars %>%
  ggvis() %>%
  layer_points(x = ~ wt, y = ~ mpg) %>% 
  add_data(data = data.frame(x = mtcars$wt, 
                             y = 49.931 - 13.380 * mtcars$wt + 1.171 * mtcars$wt^2)[order(mtcars$wt), ]) %>% 
  layer_paths(x = ~ x, y = ~ y, stroke := "red")
```